# How to fix size of powerline in Spacemacs?

Tags: powerline, spacemacs

How to fix size of powerline in Spacemacs?

Somehow my powerline changed in size.

Screenshot: [[image]

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: @Muds yep, when i change the theme( SPC T-n ), size becomes normal, but if i push any button than powerline has changed again.

Answer (score 0):

> How to fix size of powerline in Spacemacs?

It seems like [problem with unicode](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1012).

Solution for Fedora 23:
sudo dnf install adobe-source-code-pro-fonts

Answer (score 0):

Change the powerline-scale to 1.1 
And It will fix the problem

```
dotspacemacs-default-font '("Consolas"
                               :size 16
                               :weight normal
                               :width normal
                               :powerline-scale 1.1)
```